# Swift 4 -Check if image HD or no

Tags: swift

I have app Upload images to firebase and I want check if image 720p *HD* or no because I want show user only available 720p or 1080p.

If anyone know how to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this extention method if you have an UIImage

```
extension UIImage {

    func isImageHD() -> Bool {

        let heightInPoints = self.size.height
        let heightInPixels = heightInPoints * self.scale

        return heightInPixels >= 720
    }
}
```

you can use this where you have the UIImage

```
let image = // Your image 

if image.isImageHD() {

// Upload Image 

} else {

// Show Pop up or something

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help How to use this with [ if ] like if heightInPxels >= 720 { upload } else {no upload func }.  And thanks